# Can I merge two broadband Internet connections into one?

Tags: internet, connection

I would like to merge 2 identical Internet connections into one. 
I have two 512 connections and would like to combine them to create a single 1 M BPS connection.

I hope you can help.

Comment: Haha - awesome edit Kara

Comment: indeed, miraculous edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called [multihoming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming). There are a few network appliances that offer this, and it can also be configured on a computer with 3 or more network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If the two internet connections are from the same provider, the provider should be able to connect them for you.  If not, then you can't merge them, but there are ways to get good use from both of them. The question linked below has a good discussion of the issues.

[2 DSL lines...any benefit?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58525/2-dsl-lines-any-benefit)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiConnect from http://asurasoft.awardspace.com/abtmulticonnect.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can with the use of connectify dispatch, Follow the link below for complete details:
http://technokarak.com/how-to-combine-multiple-internet-connections-for-faster-speed-and-increased-reliability.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.